# ng-select content not visible on click of down arrow after search result dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-ngselect

I'm using a ng-select dropdown to dynamically search the data.

The only issue is that the content is not visible when you click the down arrow once the search result is discovered, even though I was able to implement the search as planned.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-xtmcpu

Steps to reproduce:

step 1: click on search box

step 2: search a number, for eg : 1

step 3: click down arrow

[image]

[image]

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per what I can understand, it seems that this the style that you applied in the html that interfers with the size of the elements being displayed underneath the input (after removing it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-aecymo)
This is actually the default behavior of ng-select. You can bypass it by removing your style or by applying custom style to the items.

Comment: Yeah, it is true that the feature will work after removal of image from the options section. But here specifically i have a requirement to display an image with some specific size as specified in the example.